# How to connect to a Lotus Notes Database without Password dialog via C API

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I'm trying to connect to a nsf mail database to read out some mails in MIME format. This should be done periodically and unattended. Via COM Interop i could use the NotesSession.Initialize method to provide a password for the database. But i need the MIME conversion routines that are not exposed via COM. I checked the C API but it seems that there is no way to pass in a password anywhere. Result is that i'm confronted with Notes own login dialog when connecting to the database via NSFDbOpen or NSFDbOpenExtended. I would prefer to not mix COM and C API calls. Uncontrollable problems might air from that.

If have seens the extpwd example in the documentation but changing the notes Installation via an Extension Manager Addin is not really an option either. There should be an easier way. COM can so the C API can hopefully also.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up Single Sign On for the Notes Client, then you won't get the password prompt.

Additionally, you could/should set "Don't prompt for a password from other Lotus Notes-based programs".

From the documentation:

> You have Lotus Notes open in the background, and you are working in a
>   Lotus® Notes-based program, you can set Lotus Notes to remember your
>   password, so you don't have to enter your password multiple times.
>
> Click File > Security > User Security (Macintosh OS X users: Lotus
>   Notes > Security > User Security). Click Security Basics, and select
>   "Don't prompt for a password from other Lotus Notes-based programs
>   (reduces security)" under "Your Login and Password Settings."